# I'm having problem to write this code correctly

Tags: php, ajax

I want to add this  line

```
 a href="r.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >Details>
```

which will display details of this id on another page.
but i don't know how to write this line correctly. can you help me please thank you.

```
 $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbmtc');
 $perPage = 10;
 $page = 0;
  if (isset($_POST['page'])) { 
    $page  = $_POST['page']; 
  } else { 
    $page=1; 
  };  
$startFrom = ($page-1) * $perPage;  
$sqlQuery = "SELECT fname, lname, dept, email
    FROM staff ORDER BY fname ASC LIMIT $startFrom, $perPage";  
    //echo $sqlQuery;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery); 
$paginationHtml = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
    $paginationHtml.='<tr>';  
    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["fname"].' '.$row["lname"].'</td>';
    
    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["dept"].'</td>';

    $paginationHtml.='<td>'.$row["email"].'</td>';

   **this line should be here**
    
    $paginationHtml.='</tr>';  
    
} 
$jsonData = array(
    "html"  => $paginationHtml, 
);
echo json_encode($jsonData); 
?>
```

This part is in index.php

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                      <th>Email</th>                 
                     <th>Operations</th>
               
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="content">     
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vTF9.png)

And when i insert
`$paginationHtml .= '<td><a href="r.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Details</a></td>';`

I got this I don't why, that why I said it's not good
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggdot.png)

Comment: `$paginationHtml .= '<td><a href="r.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Details</a></td>';` ?

Comment: I  already wrote this before, it's not good

Comment: Please, explain _"it's not good"_. Also, the tag `<table>` is missing. Your SQL query is open to SQL injections (`$_POST['page']` is not a trusted value).

Comment: What is the error you are getting because @Syscall comment is correct, so probably your `$row[id]` might have wrong value

Comment: `it's not good`...sorry can you be more specific about what is wrong when you try that code. We can't fix vague issues.

Comment: ok I edit the post, I put a screenshot what happen when I insert this line. that why I said it's not good sorry

Comment: @Aaliyah: You didn't select the ID in your sql query.

Comment: Ok thank you guys it's working, I forgot to add id in my sql query

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You didn't select the ID in your sql query. Please add it in the selected fieds.

These are the possibilities to write this and you can choose one of them:

```
  1-  $paginationHtml .= '<td><a href="r.php?id='.$row['id'].'" >Details</a></td>';
  2-  $paginationHtml .= "<td><a href=\"r.php?id={$row['id']}\" >Details</a></td>";
```